# Connecting to a 2nd DB gives me no results when querying

Tags: functions, database, query, errors

I'm trying to access a different DB on the same localhost as my wp db is and I did this like so:

functions.php:

```
add_action('init','my_new_db');
function my_new_db(){
 $newdb = new wpdb( 'test', 'test',  'test',  'localhost');
 $newdb->show_errors();
}
```

Following this in page.php:

```
  <?php
  global $newdb;

  $test = $newdb->prepare( "SELECT `...`, `...` FROM ..." );
  $result = $newdb->get_results($test);

  return($result);

   ?>
```

The dots are correctly filled in don't worry about that, though this is the message I query and I get no error or no result.

Comment: Where are `$DB_USER`, etc. (the variables) set? You are calling them inside a function, so if you set them in the global scope, they won't be available in your function. Please read about PHP and scope.

Comment: Wait I did change it but forgot to change it here, please check out the code again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a variable scope, an pure PHP, problem at heart.

I didn't close it because I am assuming that mistake is in turn due to a misunderstanding of the `init` hook, or hooks in general perhaps, which is WordPress specific.

1. In PHP, a global must be declared `global` *before* the first time
   it is used.
2. The `init` hook fires very early in page load, long before your
   `page.php` executes
3. Your `$newdb` variable is not declared `global` until `page.php`
4. Thus, the variable is declared `global` after it has been used in
   the `init` action, and thus *too late*.

PHP executes line by line in sequence. Order matters. The order that hooks fire determines the order of the code in any of the "attached" functions.

To fix this, declare your variable `global` in the callback to the `init` action hook.

```
add_action('init','my_new_db');
function my_new_db(){
  global $newdb;
  $newdb = new wpdb( 'test', 'test',  'test',  'localhost');
  $newdb->show_errors();
}
```

You will still need `global $newdb;` in your `page.php` file to access the global you've created. Don't remove that.

Comment: Dum, you always happen to learn me a lesson thank you! Although now i've removed the `global $newdb` from the `page.php`. I still do not have any results from my query it strangely enough doesn't even give me an error.

Comment: You will ___also___ need the `global $newdb;` in `page.php`. Don't remove it.

Comment: I removed it only because with it gave no responses, so I guess even with it no errors/results are shown.

Comment: Use `var_dump` instead of `return` to test the code.

Comment: Huh, why do return/echo not work but var_dump/print_r does? Even better, how am I supposed to show the data without it being thrown out there with all the arrays/variables?

Comment: You are asking questions about basic PHP [array](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [object](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) syntax. Consult PHP's very good documentation. This is no longer about WordPress, and honestly it was a stretch in the first place.

Comment: That seems strange to me because in PHP you can just declare the connections and make function for that. Though in Wordpress I need to use this different method i'm not familiar with, therefore I don't even know what to ask to a PHP specialist/based forum.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13415/discussion-between-s-ha-dum-and-user3121076)